# How do I create a drop down menu inside of a command with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, menu, discord.py

I was going to make a rock paper scissors game with discord.py and I first defaulted to using select menus in messages, that would work if I could find a way to do it, so then I decided to just   make it use a string object, but then I thought to myself it would not be easy if the user had to guess what the choices where, so then I wanted to include a select menu inside of a slash command like the one you get from this code:

```
@tree.command(name="boolean_test", description="Boolean test")
async def boolean_test(command, boolean: bool):
    pass
```

but I could not find a way to do that.
I'm not using any forks of discord.py

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

- `choices`
- `Literal`
- `Enum`

The docs page for [`choices`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.choices) shows an example for all three of them. The one you decide to go for depends on your use case. For example, `Choice`s have a `value` attribute that you can use to make them easier to work with internally (like attaching an id to the choices instead of the raw strings).